# PHP filter dropdown list does not show the result after clicking on the items

Tags: php, html

I have this code

```
<div class="row opening-input">
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7 ct-input mb-2">
        <select class="custom-select input-sl h-6" name="country">
            <option value="">Country</option>
            <option value="291">Indonesia</option>
            <option value="290">Myanmar</option>
            <option value="289">Bangladesh</option>
            <option value="288">Pakistan</option>
            <option value="287">China</option>
            <option value="287">Singapore</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 ct-input mb-2">
        <select class="custom-select input-sl h-6 ">
            <option value="">Type</option>
            <option value="1">Part-time</option>
            <option value="2">Full-time</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="opening-table table-responsive container-col-ev ">
    <table class="table ">
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($career as $item): ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="career-tb" scope="row" ><a href="<?php the_permalink($item->ID); ?>"><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title($item->ID), 15, '...'); ?></a></th>
                    <td class="career-dc"><i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt"></i><span>Indonesia</span></td>
                    <td class="career-time"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i><span><?= get_field('time_work', $item->ID); ?></span></td>
                    <td class="text-end"><a href="<?php the_permalink($item->ID); ?>"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right cl-or "></i></a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

When I tried to click on the items in the dropdown list, it did not give me back the list of the job filter by country or type.

[problem-in-picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWJ4k.png)

Could anyone help me fix this code? Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @vinh2201, we're going to need more information than a tiny snippet of code. I can't see how you're planning on filtering the countries or anything. Are you able to please provide more information?

Comment: Hello @Joshua, thank you for your reply. I have provided the picture including the problem I got above. Could you help me check it? Thank you.